# E text editor puts dash when embedding ruby in html

Tags: erb

When I do some commands in e text editor,

```
<% form_for(:session, :url => sessions_path) do |f| -%>

<% end -%>
```

it adds the dash in `-%>`, does this affect anything? How can I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.06.html#topics-trimspaces):

> Since 2.6.0, `<%= -%>` remove tail spaces and newline.

This is typically used with ERb tags that don't print anything to reduce the number of superfluous whitespace in the outputted HTML.